# Issue with binary install of moveit2 with ROS2 Humble in Ubuntu 22.02

Tags: ros2, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I am trying to install moveit2 with ROS2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.02, but I came across the issue https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/issues/1442. It says that version 2.5.3 was released about 5 days ago, but the ROS repository still only includes 2.5.1. Is there a way to know when will it be available? (I though replying to the issue, but I was afraid it would reopen the issue)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404556/issue-with-binary-install-of-moveit2-with-ros2-humble-in-ubuntu-22.02/) by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 230 on 2022-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two different repositories in ROS ecosystem, namely main and testing. The releases become available in testing repositories almost as soon as they merged to rosdistro (after they are compiled in build farm). They get synced in main repositories every month or so and become available for most people. You can follow the announcements in ROS discourse for syncs. A sample announcement is here: https://discourse.ros.org/t/preparing-for-rolling-sync-2022-07-15/26476. If you want to get access to latest releases before syncs happen you can build from source or use testing repositories. Please note testing repositories are bleeding edge and may contain regressions. To enable testing repositories, simply issue the following command in your terminal:

```
echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros2-testing/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list
```

---

Originally posted by [vatanaksoytezer](https://answers.ros.org/users/78200/vatanaksoytezer/) with karma: 26 on 2022-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1